# Необходимые для заполнения поля

Tags: вёрстка

Какие поля стоит делать обязательными для заполнения, а какие - нет? Например, есть поле типа `username`, незаполнение которого приведет к неверному (или некачественному) отображению информации на сайте. А поле для ввода текста в сообщении на форуме? Часто можно видеть всплывающее окно с текстом ошибки:

> Поле сообщения должно содержать не менее 5 символов.

Есть ли смысл делать подобные поля обязательными или ставить проверку в них на количество введенных символов? Пользователь может ввести `djlks` - те же 5 символов, в виде не имеющей смысла последовательности. Проверять осмысленность сообщения все равно не получится. В этой ситуации `djlks` ничем не лучше пустого сообщения. Так стоит ли подобные поля делать обязательными?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть два интересных ответа на этот вопрос. Первый ответ от программистов — есть предметная область, которая моделируется программой. Программа требует наличия тех полей, которые обязательны в предметной области.

Конечно, модель — это всего лишь абстракция, и при её построении часть информации из реального мира просто игнорируется. Но та часть, которая используется в алгоритмах, должна присутствовать обязательно.

Второй ответ от проектировциков взаимодействия (интерфейса) — изложен в книгах Алана Купера. Он считает, что программы слишком прямолинейны, когда речь идёт о вводе информации. Человек, заполняющий большой формуляр, может отложить его на время и вернуться к его заполнению позже, но программа обычно этого не позволяет. Вы ввели 50 полей из 100 и хотите временно заняться чем то другим? Нельзя. Вводите оставшиеся 50 или теряйте всё, что вы уже ввели.

Ну а та проверка, о которой Вы написали — это определённая защита не только от пустых сообщений, но и от мусора `+1`, и прочего. Она может защитить от неумышленных ошибок, но от умышленных, конечно, не защитит.

Жизнерадостный дебил из каментов, обычно достаточно настойчив, чтобы вместо нетленки `+1` вписать нетленку. Но здесь начинают работать социальные механизмы.